# Is there any utility function in Tensorflow.js similar to Python/Keras's to_categorical()?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I've recently began working with tensorflow.js. I've reached a point where I need to one hot encode an output. I found nothing searching the tensorflow.js api (*tensorflow api has exactly what i'm searching for as a utility but I'm using javascript*) regarding to my case and the only help I found from google is python/keras to_categorical().

I want to know for sure from somebody that's been through this before with tensorflow.js because I'm about to implement my own function based on python/keras to_categorical() source code so, is there any similar util function that I can use to one hot encode straight from the tensorflow.js api?

Comment: tensorflow.js, [one-hot](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#oneHot)

Comment: It never went through my mind to search for "onehot" inside the docs instead of "categorical". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on 4.Pi.n comment -> [one-hot](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#oneHot) if anybody else doesn't know how to search the docs the right way.